# Spring bean with @Async method, why singleton bean‘s inner hashcode is different from outside

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, hashcode

I'm very confused with the the different behaviors in spring bean with async mehtod. i have a Demo Bean with an @Async method that just print this.hashCode(). and a Main class that injected by Demo. The Demo bean'scope is singleton. but in fact, in Main class, the demo.hashcode() is not equal to this.hashCode() in the method test() of Demo class. why? they are not the same instance?

```
@Component
public class Demo {
    @Async
    public void test(){
        System.out.println(this.hashCode());
    } 
}
```

```
@Component
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    Demo demo;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
         System.out.println(demo.hashcode());
         demo.test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Main` you are calling the `hashCode()` method on the **proxy** object. To support `@Async` Spring places the concrete object inside a proxy to wrap the `@Async` logic around the concrete method call. Therefore you get the `hashCode` value of the proxy.

When invoking `demo.hashCode()` you are returning the `hashCode()` of the **concrete** object and **not** the proxy anymore. Therefore they differ.

Comment: That's exactly the reason for the behaviour.